# YouTube api: what is the use of private in the privacyStatus?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was playing around with `YouTube data V3 api` and came across the `privacyStatus` option in the `BroadcastParameters`.

So, as we know that YouTube offers you tree options:

1. Public (self explanatory)
2. Private (only to shared email addresses)
3. Unlisted (only to shared links)

And then i came across this post [How can I set videos to "private yet shared" using the v3 YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579534/how-can-i-set-videos-to-private-yet-shared-using-the-v3-youtube-api).

Now the thing i couldn't get my head around is that why there is even a private feature if we couldn't add email adderesses from the API? or am i missing something? is there another way to add users?

any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how YouTube works.

Public videos can be viewed by all.    Private videos can be viewed only by the owner.   Unlisted videos can be viewed by anyone with the link to the video.

there is no option for sharing a video with specific user id email address.

IMO alot of the limitations of the YouTube API are due to the fact that Google baught YouTube it wasn't designed by them so probably has backend limitations that prevent this as well as leed to the issue of authorization to a channel instead of a user.