# How do I set a video to "shared privately" using the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

```
I'm uploading videos privately with the YouTube API.

Additionally, I want to set up private internal sharing.

I can do it from the screen, but I want to do it with the API.

If there is any way, please let me know.

thank you.
```

java - How can I set videos to "private yet shared" using the v3 YouTube API? - Stack Overflow [How can I set videos to "private yet shared" using the v3 YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579534/how-can-i-set-videos-to-private-yet-shared-using-the-v3-youtube-api#new-answer)

```
i'm having a similar problem. What is the issue now?
```

```
I'm uploading videos privately with the YouTube API.

Additionally, I want to set up private internal sharing.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
  // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
  Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

  // Default is to be publicly visible.
  VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
  status.setPrivacyStatus("private");
  videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

  ...

  YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = getYoutube().videos()
    .insert(Arrays.asList("snippet","statistics","status"), videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
```

Comment: I want to set not only private settings, but also private sharing destinations.

How should I set the email address etc. of the sharing destination?